# How can I replace part of a Match in Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, full-text-search

I have a string looking like this

```
<span class=SpellE>Content</span>
```

and I also have a regular expression that searches for that kind of phrases in my text and more spiecialy for a phrase :

```
"\w</span>"
```

In other words : a  with a symbol right in front of it except for space.

So, I have this:

```
const string pattern = "\\w</span>";
const string replace = "&nbsp;</span>";
var rgx = new Regex(pattern);
var resultAfterRegex = rgx.Replace(result, replace);
return resultAfterRegex;
```

But in the result it substitutes also and the letter right before the  and I am losing it.
It comes like this :

**Conten_** with the **t** missing in the end.

Do you have any idea how I could replace only the   without the letter in front of it?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: the problem is that this is losing the t at the end of content which adding in that space won't help with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the regex is consuming everything that is matched including the single letter.

The way to do it is as follows:

```
const string pattern = "(\\w)</span>";
const string replace = "$1&nbsp;</span>";
```

What this does is capture the single letter match using the `()` and then putting it into the replaced string using `$1`.

As pointed out by @dasblinkenlight you could also use non-capturing lookbehind as follows:

```
const string pattern = "(?<=\\w)</span>";
const string replace = "&nbsp;</span>";
```

The pattern here uses special syntax to say very roughly that the `\w` must be there but is not part of the actual match. So this method is probably closer to what you want since it matches just the thing you want to replace.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx for details on regex syntax as well as links to more detailed explanations.

Comment: +1 for properly diagnosing the problem. Using a non-capturing lookbehind `"(?<=\\w)</span>"` would probably be a better solution, though.

Comment: Thank you.But why is that syntax $1. What does it actually says? I guess that $ stands for 'select' but why is the '1' ?

Comment: @mathinvalidnik: That syntax says use the first group captured by the regex. If you had two groups then $2 would be the second, etc. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx for more details on the syntax of regular expressions.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Quite probably that would be better, yes. I always forget about the more advanced bits of regex though. I've edited my answer to include your suggestions now.